# Calling SQLite3.SetDirectory gives a System.AccessViolationException on Windows 8.1 (WinRT)

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8.1, sqlite-net

In my Windows 8.1 (WinRT) app I am using [SQLite v 3.8.9](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d04f82f-2fe9-4727-a2f9-a2db127ddc9a) with [SQLite-net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net/) as my database, and [SemaphoreSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) as my synchronization enforcer. It usually works, but sometimes it crashes in the SQLite's C++ code when I try to delete a table entry.

> First-chance exception at *(code)* in *(project name)*: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location *(location)*.

#### Delete table entry

```
private static SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1,5);
public void DeleteItem(Item item)
{
    _mutex.Wait();
    using (var connection = new SQLiteConnection(Path))
    {
         connection.Delete(item);
    }
    _mutex.Release();
}
```

#### SQLite.cs

```
public SQLiteConnection (string databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, bool storeDateTimeAsTicks = false)
{
    ...
#if NETFX_CORE
        SQLite3.SetDirectory(/*temp directory type*/2, Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.Path);
#endif
    ...
}
```

The crash happens when `SQLite3.SetDirectory` is called.

Exception:

> [`System.AccessViolationException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.accessviolationexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Message:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Stacktrace:

> at SQLite.SQLite3.SetDirectory(UInt32 directoryType, String directoryPath)
>
> at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, SQLiteOpenFlags openFlags, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
>
> at SQLite.SQLiteConnection..ctor(String databasePath, Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)

#### Question

I am guessing that this must be a Threading issue because it usually works and has irregular crashes; but I am unable to find anything.

**What can be the cause of the exception and what can I do to fix it?**

*I do not think it is corrupted memory, maybe protected, but I am fairly sure that only one of my threads are accessing it*

Comment: I am experiencing same issue on usage in multi thread scenario. The connections are not shared between threads. Did you find any solutions to this problem?

Comment: @byte nope, no solution yet :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, even though I was confident that only one thread was accessing the SQLite db at a time, it turned out that I had some minor code that I didn't expect was called at the same time; this caused the `AccessViolationException`

To ensure that this problem does not arise in the future, I did the following:

- Moved the whole SQLite code to a different project in an attempt to isolate it.
- Implemented a semi-factory pattern in the project to ensure that only one thread uses it (this also made the code look better)

**Factory Database class**

```
public class DataBaseConnection: SQLite.SQLiteConnection
{
   private const string _path = "MySQlitePath";
   private static SemaphoreSlim _contextMutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 5);
   private DataBaseConnection() : base(_path)
   {
   }

   public static DataBaseConnection CreateDataBaseConnection()
   {
       _contextMutex.Wait();
       return new DataBaseConnection();
   }

   private bool disposed = false;
   protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
       if (disposed)
          return;
       if(disposing)
       {
          
       }
       disposed = true;
       base.Dispose(disposing);
       _contextMutex.Release();
    }
}
```

Using the factory

```
using (var connection = DataBaseConnection.CreateDataBaseConnection())
{
     connection.Delete(item);
}
```

Since using this, I've never seen the `AccessViolationException` again.

---

#### Using Multiple DB connections

If you are using Multiple Connections (i.e. different DB paths) such as:

- MySQlitePath_1
- MySQlitePath_2
- ...
- MySQlitePath_N

You should use the same Synchronization Mechanism (in my case `SemaphoreSlim`) throughout to ensure **only one** SQLite Connection is open at any given time; even though they are accessing different files.